# Нужно ли тире в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп

Вышла на балкон захотелось погулять, села на кровать перехотелось.

Answer (score 2):

**Вышла на балкон — захотелось погулять, села на кровать — перехотелось.**

Смысл таков: когда я(она) вышла на балкон, мне(ей) захотелось погулять; когда я(она) села на кровать, мне(ей) перехотелось гулять.

Подробности здесь: [Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)